# Computing Type I error

Tags: probability

I am trying to compute the Type I error test for the following:

$X_1, X_2,\ldots,X_8$ is a random sample of size 8 from a Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda$. Reject the null hypothesis, $H_0: \lambda = 0.5$ vs $H_1: \lambda > 0.5$ if the observed $\sum_{i=1}^{8} x_i \ge 8$

What I've done so far,

$$Y= X_1 + X_2 +\cdots+ X_8 \ge 8$$

since $Y$ is a sum of iid Poisson random variables,

$$\gamma(\lambda) = P(Y\ge 8 \mid \mu=\lambda)$$

$$= \sum_{i=1}^{8} \frac{e^{-8\lambda}(8\lambda)^i}{i!}$$

$$= e^{-8}8\lambda + \frac{e^{-8\lambda}(8\lambda^2)}{2} + \cdots + \frac{e^{-8\lambda}(8\lambda^8)}{8!}$$

I've computed various values of $\gamma(\lambda)$ thinking that could be of use?

$\lambda: 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2$

$\gamma(\lambda): 0.96, 0.84, 0.59, 0.33, 0.15, 0.06, 0.02$

I was thinking for an alpha value of 0.05, $\lambda$ = 2 would produce a Type I error.

Comment: You wrote $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^8$ but when you listed the terms individually you started with $i=0$ rather than $i=1$. And that's the probability of $Y\le 8$, not of $Y\ge 8$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I did realize this when I wrote this after on paper. The first term should be removed. I will do that now. Thank you for your checking

Comment: Why are you using $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^8$ rather than $\displaystyle\sum_{i=8}^\infty = 1 - \sum_{i=0}^7\,{}$? ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good job in calculation, but be cautious in interpreting concepts.

By definition, type I error is the probability that rejects $H_0$ when $H_0$ is true. So the answer should be $\gamma(\color{red}{0.5})$ since $\lambda = 0.5$ in $H_0$.

In particular, it is independent of the significance level chosen by researcher, that is, it can be computed without any information of $\alpha$ (The statement "$\lambda = 2$ would produce a Type error" is incorrect).

Comment: I see your point. Thank you for the explanation.